# Where can I download jQuery timers?

Tags: jquery, plugins, timer

It seems to have disappeared from the top of Google. I've searched teh jQuery site, no results, the top results on Google are either dead links.
The links on http://plugins.jquery.com/node/3656/release don't lead to downloads.

I'm not a noob but something messed up has happened.

**EDIT:**

As per the replies:

"The top hit on the big G for "jquery timers download" is jquery.offput.ca/every – T.J. Crowder"

That links to a page that says:
"jQuery timers has been moved to the jQuery plugin repository where updates, bug tracking and documentation can be centralized. Please go there to ensure you have the newest version of the code."

Following that link shows a list of plugins that DOES NOT INCLUDE jQuery timers.

@ T.J. Crowder, perhaps you chould go more than 1 link deep after Google searching.

The reply from Darin Dimitrov is in the same situation.

The link from VirtualBlackFox goes to the jQuery website. Which I assume you then click on "Downloads -> View all releases" but there is no download link there either.

Comment: The top hit on the big G for "jquery timers download" is http://jquery.offput.ca/every/

Comment: Why do you feel the need to specifically state that you are not a so-called *noob*?

Comment: Because it seems foolish to not be able to find a link to a common jQuery plugin. Especially when you are a commercial web developer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the releases page](http://plugins.jquery.com/node/3656/release) it looks like 1.2 is the latest, and there's a copy of 1.2 on [github here](http://github.com/patryk/jquery.timers/blob/master/jquery.timers.js) ("imported from ... no idea").

Hopefully that's what you're looking for. Otherwise I'd suggest you email Blair (email in the comments in that git version) and ask him where the official version's kept. In fact I suggest you email him anyway to get the jquery pages up-to-date at least.

Comment: thanks man, I wonder why this one has been so hard to find nowadays ;)

Answer (score 0):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers

A download link is provided on its old homepage: http://jquery.offput.ca/timers/

Comment: This page contains no link to download the plugin

Comment: That is a very old version of the plugin.

Comment: This link no longer exists. Just redirects to jquery.com