# Clear interval in Tampermonkey script, that was set in another script

Tags: javascript, setinterval, tampermonkey

I have a tampermonkey script that I will use infrequently; manually turning it on when I need it.
I also have another TM script running on the same page (not mine), that has an interval running which I would like to terminate when I have my script running (it's throwing exceptions in the console every 500ms).

**Question:** Is it possible to terminate an interval from one tampermonkey script that was set by another?

I ultimately don't need the other script running when this one is running; so if there is another way to disable it automatically when my script is turned on, that would work fine.

Comment: I expect TM's scripts (like GreaseMonkey's) are sandboxed so what you're asking is unlikely. Wouldn't it be easier to fix the script that's generating all the errors?

Comment: Timers are part of DOM so they can be easily cleared regardless of their scripting origin. The only problem is that there's no way to find the exact timer id so the only impractical solution is [to stop all timers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8832353), or - your best bet - the timers set since the last check before the offending timer was set.

Comment: No.  You can rewrite both scripts to communicate with each other. That's it.  Otherwise, just switch off script A when you switch on script B (two clicks in the Tampermonkey menu), and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was beginning to think that was going to be the case.Looks like it may be easier in the end to just turn the other one off when I need to use it.